# What is diffrence between ReferenceField And GenericReferenceField?

Tags: python, mongoengine

In mongoengine fields

What is diffrence between ReferenceField And GenericReferenceField? both appears similar to me can someone make it clear with example if possible

Answer (score 1):

ReferenceField is used when you need to do a reference on a specific Model while that GenericReferenceField is used when you need to do reference on several different models

Example: you assume that a person can do a post but a company can't it but a person or company can be a car's owner

```
class Person(Document):
      name = StringField()

class Company(Document):
      name = StringField()

class Post(Document):
      owner = ReferenceField(Person) # it can be only reference to Person Model

class Car(Document):
      owner = GenericReferenceField() # it can be a Reference to any Model
```